# Call the hybrid_method of a particular record on all records in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I'm using the SQLAlchemy ORM. I have tables `Table1` and `Table2`. I have a record/object of type `Table1` `foo`. `foo` has a hybrid_method `bar(baz)`. I want to select all objects `tab` of type `Table2` such that `foo.bar(tab.prop)` is True. How would I do that?

As far as I know, instance-specific methods can't operate on columns, though maybe I'm missing some incantation.

I tried using `func`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Some code:

```py
class Table1(BaseTable):
  @hybrid_method
  def bar(self, baz):
    return ...

foo=Table1()
#What should work, but doesn't
select(Table2.id).where(foo.bar(Table2.col1))

#Also tried
bar=foo.bar
select(Table2.id).where(func.bar(Table2.col1))
```

Comment: can you show some code and what you have tried here?

Comment: @python_user I added some example code.